# Having trouble using MySQLi INSERT queries

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay, so I'm updating my site from `MySQL` to `MySQLi`, which means I have to re-code some of the database stuff.

I looked on php.net on how to use `MySQLi` queries to insert data into a table and did exactly what they said to, but no luck.

Here's my connection variable:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
```

And here is the code to insert the data:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users ('user', 'pass', 'email') VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
```

It doesn't reply with any errors, and it just takes me to the intended landing page. It doesn't actually add the data to the table though.

Any ideas?

Comment: The column names should be delimited with `\`\`` and not with `''`

Comment: you don't have to delimited the column name

Comment: @demonking You don't, but if you do, it should be done correctly.

Comment: @Boaz yes, you are right, but it's optional ;)

Answer (score 1):

As answered above, removing the quotes from the column names will solve your problem:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (user, pass, email) VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
```

But I also noted that your script is vulnerable against SQL injection attacks.
In `MySQLi` you can [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) your statements before execution, so you will be sure that no one will inject SQL commands in your database.

If you don't want to prepare each sql statements before execution, at least use the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function, that will protect your system against SQL injection too. Use like that:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (user, pass, email) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($user) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($pass) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($email) . "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

remove single quotes from column names

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (user, pass, email) VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
```

OR

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (`user`, `pass`, `email`) VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
```